# Как вырезать цифры PHP?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Как в строке

```
Заявка: № 142898 от Аптека №Дн028 бла-бла-бла
```

вырезать цифры после № (может быть или нет пробел, цифр может быть от 6 до 8)?

Пробую

```
$arTask['TITLE'] = "Заявка: № 142898 от Аптека №Дн028 бла-бла-бла";
preg_match_all('/№\s(\d[6,8])/iu', $arTask['TITLE'], $OUT, PREG_SET_ORDER);
print_r($OUT)
```

получаю пустой массив.

Comment: У вас `\s` обязательный, а также вместо фигурных скобок квадратные.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно получить результат с помощью

```
$arTask = "Заявка: № 142898 от Аптека №Дн028 бла-бла-бла";
if (preg_match_all('/№\s*\K\d{6,8}/u', $arTask, $OUT)) {
 print_r($OUT[0]);
}
```

См. [демо-код на PHP](https://ideone.com/VSRwC9). Если количество цифр от 6 и выше, можно удалить восьмёрку: `'/№\s*\K\d{6,}/u'`.

См. [демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/vOfY5p/1).

**Подробности**

- `№` - символ `№`
- `\s*` - 0 и более пробельных символов
- `\K` - оператор, удаляющий весь текст из текущего буфера совпадения
- `\d{6,8}` - от 6 до 8 цифр (если заменить на плюс — 1 и более цифр)

Answer (score 0):

Можно так же с помощью preg_replace()

```
$str = 'Заявка: № 142898 от Аптека №Дн028 бла-бла-бла';

echo preg_replace('~.+№\s?(\d{6,8}).+~', '$1', $str);
```